# Gmail: how to embed another email

Tags: gmail, embed, gmail-attachments

How to embed an existing email from the same gmail account into a new email?

I am aware that I can use *Forward* but in my case I have a threaded email that already contains a conversation and I would like to have another email(s) embedded while maintaining the conversation in the thread. Also you cannot forward more than one email in the same message.

All the solutions that come up on google are about exporting the email to a PDF and then attaching that file which is obviously not the same thing, since I want to be able to copy an existing email and then paste it into another email in the same way I can paste an image or text content, preserving all the HTML formatting, headers and metadata, i.e. in a way similar to how .EML files work on desktop email clients.

I tried dragging the email I need into the Compose form but that has no effect. Although the email is draggable it is apparently only for moving into a specific folder, and *not* for embedding into another email.

Apparently google does not yet have any support for embedded emails, or did I miss something?

What would be the workaround for preserving the embedded email as formatted text with headers and all the metadata? (apart from *Forward* which would break the conversation thread in my case and won't allow forwarding multiple emails)